# Multivariable limit with parameters

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For every point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $a + b = 1$, find the limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}\frac{y\sin\pi x}{x+y-1}$$
We have three cases, $a = 0 $ and $ b=1,$ $b=0$ and $ a=1$, and finally $a, b\not\in\{0,1\} $. I solved the first case, there was no limit, but I have no idea how to tackle the rest of them.

Comment: You can show $\mathbb{R}^2$, writting *\mathbb{R}^2* in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $\begin{cases}x=a+u &,& u\to 0\\ y=b+v &,& v\to 0\end{cases}$ written in this way, it is easier to exploit $a+b=1$.

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{(b+v)\sin(a\pi+u\pi)}{u+v}=\dfrac{\overbrace{(b+v)}^{\to b}\big(\sin(a\pi)\overbrace{\cos(u\pi)}^{\to 1}+\overbrace{\sin(u\pi)}^{\to 0}\cos(a\pi)\big)}{u+v}$

- case $a=1,\ b=0$

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{v\sin(\pi+u\pi)}{u+v}=\dfrac{-v\sin(u\pi)}{u+v}\sim -\pi\ \dfrac{uv}{u+v}$ and this has no limit in $(0,0)$.

See this post: [Does $\lim \frac{xy}{x+y}$ exist at (0,0)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119884/does-lim-fracxyxy-exist-at-0-0)

- case $\sin(a\pi)=0$ and $b\neq 0\quad$ (i.e. $a=n,\ b=1-n$ with $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{1\}$)

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{\pm(b+v)\sin(u\pi)}{u+v}\sim \pm b\pi\ \dfrac{u}{u+v}$ and this has no single limit.

[ e.g. when $v=ku$ then limit is $\frac{\pm b\pi}{1+k}$ which varies when $k$ changes ].

- Now if we place ourselves in the frame $\sin(a\pi)\neq 0,b\neq 0$ then

$f(x,y)\sim b\sin(a\pi)\ \dfrac{1}{u+v}$ and this has no finite limit when $(u,v)\to(0,0)$.